# Добавить в готовый слайдер функцию "swipe"

Tags: javascript

Есть слайдер, можно ли в него добавить функцию перелистывания "swipe"?

```js
'use strict';
var multiItemSlider = (function() {
  return function(selector, config) {
    var
      _mainElement = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
      _sliderWrapper = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__wrapper'), // обертка для .slider-item
      _sliderItems = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // элементы (.slider-item)
      _sliderControls = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
      _sliderControlLeft = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_left'), // кнопка "LEFT"
      _sliderControlRight = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_right'), // кнопка "RIGHT"
      _wrapperWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderWrapper).width), // ширина обёртки
      _itemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderItems[0]).width), // ширина одного элемента    
      _positionLeftItem = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
      _transform = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
      _step = _itemWidth / _wrapperWidth * 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
      _items = []; // массив элементов
    // наполнение массива _items
    _sliderItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
      _items.push({
        item: item,
        position: index,
        transform: 0
      });
    });

    var position = {
      getMin: 0,
      getMax: _items.length - 1,
    }

    var _transformItem = function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'right') {
        if ((_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth - 1) >= position.getMax) {
          return;
        }
        if (!_sliderControlLeft.classList.contains('slider__control_show')) {
          _sliderControlLeft.classList.add('slider__control_show');
        }
        if (_sliderControlRight.classList.contains('slider__control_show') && (_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth) >= position.getMax) {
          _sliderControlRight.classList.remove('slider__control_show');
        }
        _positionLeftItem++;
        _transform -= _step;
      }
      if (direction === 'left') {
        if (_positionLeftItem <= position.getMin) {
          return;
        }
        if (!_sliderControlRight.classList.contains('slider__control_show')) {
          _sliderControlRight.classList.add('slider__control_show');
        }
        if (_sliderControlLeft.classList.contains('slider__control_show') && _positionLeftItem - 1 <= position.getMin) {
          _sliderControlLeft.classList.remove('slider__control_show');
        }
        _positionLeftItem--;
        _transform += _step;
      }
      _sliderWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transform + '%)';
    }

    // обработчик события click для кнопок "назад" и "вперед"
    var _controlClick = function(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('slider__control')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var direction = e.target.classList.contains('slider__control_right') ? 'right' : 'left';
        _transformItem(direction);
      }
    };

    var _setUpListeners = function() {
      // добавление к кнопкам "назад" и "вперед" обрботчика _controlClick для событя click
      _sliderControls.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', _controlClick);
      });
    }

    // инициализация
    _setUpListeners();

    return {
      right: function() { // метод right
        _transformItem('right');
      },
      left: function() { // метод left
        _transformItem('left');
      }
    }

  }
}());

var slider = multiItemSlider('.slider')
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.slider__item {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slider__control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slider__control_show {
  display: flex;
}

.slider__control:hover,
.slider__control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slider__control_left {
  left: 0;
}

.slider__control_right {
  right: 0;
}

.slider__control::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider__control_left::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider__control_right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider__item>div {
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__item">
      <div style="height: 250px; background: orange;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <div style="height: 250px; background: green;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <div style="height: 250px; background: violet;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <div style="height: 250px; background: coral;">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>
</div>
```